# Can't install NetBeans 9.0 "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer"

Tags: java, netbeans

```
~/netbeans/bin$ sh ./netbeans
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found
```

I've installed jdk-11.

Comment: what jdk versioon does you netbeans version support?